# Adding 2nd X Axis Data to Line Graphs in SSRS 2012

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm using SSRS 2012.

I'm have a simple dataset that contains only 3 fields: Date, Name, Quantity (not the exact names, but the essential descriptions).

I want to make a simple line graph, showing the Quantity for each Name over Date.

So far, no problem, Name goes in the series group, Date goes in the category group and Quantity goes into Values.

Here's the issue. I need to add the overall sum Total of Quantity as a graphed line of data, but since the Total is currently averaging between 300 - 350 per day, while no single Name will have more the 75 per day, I need to graph the Total against a 2nd, differently stepped X axis.

From what I've read, SSRS can't automatically create a Total line from the underlying data, so I altered the source query to create an 'All' entry in Name to supply the Total within the data.

However, I can't seem to get what I need to display in the graph to work. I've tried adding Name again as a Series group and adding another Quantity in the Values section and neither has worked properly

How do I add a Total line on the second X axis with different stepping?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a called a secondary axis.  Its actually quite easy.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207018(v=sql.105).aspx

Also, don't forget you can have many datasets so you can always just create another one instead of modifying your first to try an accommodate both the primary and secondary axis data in one dataset.